# not able to handling ajax request from a small chat module

Tags: php, jquery, chat

i am developing a simple chat module for my client, but not able to handle loop from `setInterval()`

Here is the js code from which i sending the request to get the data from the database

```
function getData(){

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '../../get_data.php',
        data: 'to=<?php echo $_SESSION['ch_usr_id']; ?>',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            jQuery('<div>'+data+'</div>').appendTo("#ch-data-con");
            setInterval("getData()", 5000);
        }
    });
}
```

and here is the `get_data.php` file which produce the data according to request

```
require "../../support/connection/connect_gib.php";

$to = addslashes(trim($_REQUEST['to']));

$query = "select * from chat where 
          guest_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($to)."' order by id asc";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ){
    echo "<b>".$row['frm']." : </b> " .$row['message'] . "<br />";
}
```

i got the result in loop like all the data repeat again and again, but i want the newly updated data, please make me correct what i did wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using appendTo function in jQuery.. So all chat messages will be appended after old list. You can use .html() function to replace complete data.

Another way is to get only last chat message from php side, so all data will not be repeated. You can use auto id to point which messages are fetched last.

Comment: Oh..did't see last gopal's post.

Comment: i did with your solution but one more problem i faced that i check in firebug that the request also increasing i loop means first request in 5sec. then after 5sec. the req. num is two and so oonn

Answer (score 1):

You should preserve the last id fetched and use that for new request. And on server side you should fetch from there.

```
$id= addslashes(trim($_REQUEST['id']));
$query = "select * from chat where 
          guest_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($to)."' AND id > '".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."' order by id asc";
```

function getData(){

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '../../get_data.php',
    data: 'to=<?php echo $_SESSION['ch_usr_id']; ?>&id=' + last_id_fecthed,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        jQuery('<div>'+data+'</div>').appendTo("#ch-data-con");
        setInterval("getData()", 5000);
    }
});
```

}

Comment: humm, just a minute i have to implement this and will come back soon,

Comment: i did with the solution of Vibha because it's easy but i got one more problem that i discussed in @Vibha's answer